# Installing Oracle DAC getting this error: Ins:32104 - Specified Oracle Home user is not the owner of the specified Oracle Base

Tags: oracle

I'm attempting to install Oracle Client 12c and am getting this error:

Ins:32104 -  Specified Oracle Home user is not the owner of the specified Oracle Base

I'm thinking that this machine i'm using is missing a registry key for oracle, it looks to me like it does not have an oracle home registry entry which could be causing the issue.

Is there anyway to re-add that key? Or maybe thats not the right approach?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to install a O12c Client in addition of previous Oracle products (O11g,...), in the same directory, you can use this trick:

- Let's consider that your actual Oracle Base directory is `C:\Oracle` and you cannot set the same Base directory for O12c installation (blocked by INS-32104 error code).
- You can set `C:\Oracle\Product\12.2.0` as O12c Base dir.
- Then just set `C:\Oracle\Product\12.2.0\client_1` as O12c Home dir.

OUI accepts this, the setup goes on. So you keep a *nearly standard* setup, without removing neither changing any of your previous Oracle products.

Comment: Thanks, saved my day! Should be accepted as answer.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to finalize the installation by removing the environment variable ORACLE_HOME, because in my system I have another installed client (11.2).

Comment: Tnx, save my day

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by removing previous oracle clients and manually removing files in the destination base folder (C:\oracle).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the folder was owned by `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`. Looks like it must be `Builtin\Administrators`

Could be done for example with command-line:

```
ICACLS c:\oracle\product /setowner "Administrators"
```

Add option `/T` to perform the action on all matching files/directories below the directories specified in the name.